# Passing array and display data from API to event calendar

Tags: api, axios, react-hooks, react-native

I'm using https://github.com/joshjhargreaves/react-native-event-calendar to make a simple dayview calendar in react native and get data from API. i am using axios for get data

```
 const[title,setTitle]=useState('')
    const[start,setStart]=useState('')
    const[end,setEnd]=useState('')
    const[summary,setSummary]=useState('')

  const data={
    title,
    start,
    end,
    summary
  }
  
  const[timetable,setTimetable]=useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      getData()
  },[])

  const getData=()=>{
      Axios.get('http://sh3ll.my.id/events/timetable.json')
      .then(res=>{
          console.log('res getData:', res.data)
          setTimetable(res.data)
      })
  }
```

how to passing array on events property, i cant display data from api

```
      <EventCalendar
          events={??}
          width={width}
          size={60}
          initDate={'2020-11-17'}
          scrollToFirst
        />
```

Comment: I think you must try to use your state timetable into props events. According to documentation, this props accepts array of events. This is what you retrieve from timetable.json right ?

Comment: Also, if passing the state timetable is not working on the first try, add the props renderEvent, which define how the component should display data.

Comment: @ebillis i have tried, it didn't work, yes i get data from timetable.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
const[events,setEvents]=useState([]); // default empty

const getData=()=>{
      Axios.get('http://sh3ll.my.id/events/timetable.json')
      .then(res=>{
          console.log('res getData:', res.data)
          setEvents(res.data.timetable) // set here
      })
  }



<EventCalendar
          events={events} // use here
          width={width}
          size={60}
          initDate={'2020-11-17'}
          scrollToFirst
        />
```